# How can you swap only the data of a heap Node

Tags: c, recursion, heap, pass-by-reference

I am currently stuck trying to swap the data of my heap, I know you can use recursion to swap the last and first node in the binary tree heap but I am trying to just take the data from the root and swap it with the data in the last node in effect doing the same thing but everything i have tried does not work.

I know C is a pass by reference language so i tried making a swap function that passed in a double pointer to each node but i am unable to access the data if i do that.

Here is the Code for that:

```
void swap(Node * one, Node * two){
    Node *temp = *one;
    **one->data = **two->data;
    **two->data = temp->data;
}
```

I have also tried this:

```
void swap(Node * one, Node * two){

    PData * pOne = malloc(sizeof(PData*));
    PData * pTwo = malloc(sizeof(PData*));  

    *pOne = *(PData*)one->data; 
    *pTwo = *(PData*)two->data;


    one->data = pTwo;
    two->data = pOne;
}
```

So I guess the question is, is there any other way to swap data in a heap then using recursion or a while loop?

Comment: Please include into your question the source code of the `Node` definition. Also provide an example of how this `swap()` function is being used in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have to allocate nodes just to swap a couple of data pointers. I assume that your `data` is a void pointer. If so, then this should work:

```
void swap(Node * one, Node * two){
    void* temp = one->data;
    one->data = two->data;
    two->data = temp;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this, didn't think to just create a void temp pointer.

Answer (score 0):

So i found my mistake rather quickly after posting this.

```
void swap(Node * one, Node * two){

PData * pOne = malloc(sizeof(PData));
PData * pTwo = malloc(sizeof(PData));


*pOne = *(PData*)one->data; 
*pTwo = *(PData*)two->data;

one->data = pTwo;
two->data = pOne;
}
```

in my second set of Code in the original question i was allocating space for a pointer to PData and not actually allocating enough memory for the structure itself so I was reaching into memory i did not have allocated. atleast thats what i think was happening :)

Comment: You're leaking memory. You need to free `pOne` and `pTwo` before the function exits. Although, really, you shouldn't have to allocate memory just to swap a couple of pointers. See my answer.